# Would it be ok to change a downvoted question into a completely different question so you can ask it when post-banned?

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban

I am currently still banned from posting questions on SO (even though my rep has increased more than a 100 points and I now have vote down privilege), and at least one of the questions I see hurting me I find unrecoverable.  Since I can't fix it, and it won't help to delete, would it be ok for me to "edit" the question by deleting everything and asking a different question?  Because it is extremely inconvenient for me to be banned like this (not even being throttled, just plain banned), and after having been picked for best answer recently , editing one of my questions and making it better, and trying to make another one of my questions better (but apparently failing), and making multiple accepted edits to other people's questions, but still not having the ban lifted, my only choices at this point are using one of the down-voted questions to contain a new separate unrelated question, or making a new account. So would it be ok for me to replace the entire content of one question with something else, and change the tags?

Comment: The impression I've gotten is that completely changing a question is frowned upon, especially if there are already answers to that question. For questions without comments or answers (and preferably a low view-count), I suppose you'd have more leeway, but I'd still tread carefully.

Comment: No. You're not allowed to deface your questions by removing all of the content for any reason. Neither is making a new account to get past the ban, and if you're caught doing so you can make things much worse for yourself (like having your IP address banned). Your choice at this point are to follow the instructions in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583) and get yourself unbanned in the proper manner.

Comment: Also, if it's "extremely inconvenient" for you to be banned now, it would probably be even **more** extremely inconvenient if you were permanently banned for attempting to circumvent the ban.

Comment: I'm checking some stuff out for you right now, give me a day or two...

Comment: @KenWhite there's actually a new anti-recidivism system in place that will throttle people who create new accounts (as a second chance), though I think it will still ban you completely if you screw up the second time. At least, that's what I think I've heard. The new systems are kind of complicated to understand. I'm trying to get in touch with some people who might be able to clear some things up...

Comment: @justcool393: I provided a link to what the OP (and anyone else in this position) is supposed to do. Can you not see it? It's in the last line of my first comment; the words **this post** are a link. I also addressed the reasons the OP is **not** supposed to create a new account in the same comment.

Comment: @justcool393: The OP specifically asked about the points I commented on in my previous comments (removing the content from an existing question and creating a new account to bypass the ban). I've also addressed the poster feeling held back. I'm not sure what you're debating here. Are you not reading what I've written? The proper behavior is to follow the steps to get the ban lifted; if you've ignored the signs that you were about to be banned (and there are warnings before it happens), then it's too bad if it's inconvenient for you while you take steps to get the ban lifted.

Comment: @justcool393: You really seem to be having difficulty reading the words I write. Where did I say it was "hard to create a new account"? I said that creating a new account to avoid a question ban would not be the proper way to do it, and that just creating a new account repeatedly and then continuing the same type of behavior would just end up getting your account (or IP) banned in the  future. It would be pretty pointless to ban someone, allow them to repeatedly create new accounts only to get them banned, and never do anything to stop that behavior. The *proper* solution is to get it lifted.

Comment: @justcool393: That is answered in the post I linked. There's no specific way explained to do it, just like there's no specific information about exactly what causes a ban to finally happen. If that information was public, people could abuse it by just skirting the edge of being banned, or by just barely doing enough to have it lifted. The process of getting a ban lifted is difficult *intentionally*, because it's intended as a minor punishment for repeated poor behavior. If you allow people to simply sneak around the ban, it's useless. You work to get it lifted, and then don't do it again.

Comment: @cluemein I left some comments on how to improve one of your questions. If you address those satisfactorily, I think the question would be much improved, and would get up votes / may be reopened.

Comment: Ok, I added some things including some example code.

Comment: **NO**. Unsure why you would even ask this question, the it's fairly obvious what the answer is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you allowed to completely change your question just so you can ask a question:

### **No**

However, I'm sure people have tried and some have probably gotten away with it.

But, if you do try it, it is more likely that you'll be caught and your edit will be rolled back.  And the act of editing your question twice (once for your edit and once for the rollback) will bump your question twice and get it that much more attention, and it is just as likely that you'll only push yourself even further into the ban with more downvotes.

And given all of your current questions have answers, it is much more likely you will get caught since changing the question will completely invalidate the existing answers and they will be a giant arrow point at your edit (which will probably bring more negative attention.  And you'll also could inadvertently subject your previous answerers to downvotes as well, so their answer no longer answers the question at hand.

Answer (score 3):

### No

Any attempt to **circumvent** the question ban may make your situation much worse, if you get caught.

Note that you have the possibility to ask for lifting the ban, for example based on your positive activity on other sites (I don't know how unusual it is, but as for me, it's the possibility to prove you have learned from your mistakes).

However, attempting to circumvent the ban will be a black card in your history, and you could forget about any special treatment, and risk even complete ban.

The edits that completely alter the question are considered **vandalism**.