# Should I downvote a question which doesn't deserves a downvote because the OP recycled an older question?

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

As I know, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677) post mentions about downvotes perfectly, but the cases are mostly about downvoting current state of a question, how about if the current state of a question is ok, but it is just because it is edited into a different question?

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38426773/revisions) question which is closed as unclear currently, but I don't think the current context is unclear, so I view the history and found the original question is different and terribly off topic.

While I think the current context doesn't deserves a downvote, should I downvote the question just because the context is completely changed? If I do so, do I violate the principle that 'vote for current context only'? Or I need to wait for rollback before I can downvote it?

Note: I ask it because as far as I know editing a downvoted question into another completely different question (instead of improving) is not valid here (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265301)), am I wrong for this point?

Comment: Well, the OP did what they were told to do in the [on hold] banner. There aren't any answers that would be invalidated by the edit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Are you sure the banner encourages recycling old questions, instead of fixing them? Sure, it's not as bad as if there had been any answers, still confusing though... a rollback seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editing a question to completely replace it with a different question, that is unrelated to the original quesiton, is not appropriate.  The user should have asked a new question if they had a new question, not edited a new question into an older question.

Editing the question to fix the problems with it an improve it into a good quesiton is great, but just replacing it with a different question is not.

Answer (score 6):

No, please don't downvote like this. We encourage people to edit their question if it doesn't meet the Stack Overflow standards. The 'put on hold' banner says:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38426773/edit).

Now they did so, and the last thing we need is discouraging them by giving them *more* downvotes.

There's one exception I can think of: if there are any reasonably good answers which are invalidated by the new form of the question. Though in that case, it is probably better to rollback the edit (but with your current reputation, you can't.)

It occurs to me now that the OP of that question is trying to circumvent a question ban - why would one transform the closed question into something unrelated, when you can start 'fresh' (without downvotes) by asking a new question. Still, that's something that should be solved by rolling back and/or flagging, not by downvoting.

Comment: The banner is telling them to *fix their question* and edit it to improve the *existing question*, not to just replace it with an entirely new question that's unrelated to the question there.